# How to protect admin area from users by role in laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel-5.5, acl, user-roles

I was looking for simple Laravel 5.6+ version roles and users solution. 
I want to have one `users` table. So I added `user_type` in my table as `string` in

```
$table->enum('role', ['admin', 'user']);
```

Which files should I create or update to protect everything under `/admin` route. And do not let to use `admins` routes for `users`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a middleware that is active in all /admin routes. In this middleware you should check if the user that is logged in (`Auth::user()`) has the "admin"-role.

`Auth::user()` references the `User`-model.

So in the `User`-model you can create a function like `isAdmin()`:

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->role === 'admin'
}
```

In the Middleware (or wherever you want it) you can just write

```
if(Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
    // do something if user is admin
} else {
    // do something if user is not admin
}
```

Since it is in the `User`-model you can also write `$user->isAdmin()` for regular user models.